# Oracle SP to move data from table to another

Tags: oracle, move, procedure

In my Storedprocedure , I want to move data from TableA, TableB and return a message that it is successfully copied.
Also I want to truncate TableB before moving data.
Following the SP I wrote, it gives me an error while truncating the table, how can I modify this to achieve this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_MOVE_DATA 
(
name IN VARCHAR2,
gender IN VARCHAR2,
city IN VARCHAR2,
OU_MSG OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS  
BEGIN
DECLARE
BEGIN
      execute immediate 'TRUNCATE table TableB'; 
        INSERT INTO tableB(name, gender, city)
        SELECT a.name, a.gender, a.city
        from TableA a
        where a.city in (select distinct city from ADDRESS where AREATYPE not in (4))
        OU_MSG :='Successfully moved data';
    COMMIT; 


END;
END SP_MOVE_DATA ;
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Note that you'll lose all the data of `tableb` in case of error during `insert`, because `truncate` cannot be rolled back.

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your insert statement, which isn't helping matters!

Comment: "it gives me an error" is not very helpful. What is the error message?

Comment: You don't need `select distinct city from ADDRESS ...`, using `select city from ADDRESS ...` does the same and is faster.